# Model syntax in R: how to input dynamic variables?

Tags: r, variables, dynamic, model

I want to run linear models (in this case, multivariate models with two response variables) within a `for` loop in which a new data frame called `bc_applied` is created at each iteration, as well as the vector `targets`. In my code, the column names `"target1"` and `"target2"` change at every iteration, which means I can't explicitly write variable names, instead I want to extract them from the vector `targets`.

Here is an example:

```
targets <- c("target1","target2")
bc_applied <- data.frame("dsRNA" = c(rep("gene1",5),rep("gene2",5),rep("gene3",5)),
"target1" = runif(15), "target2" = runif(15))
```

But when running

```
lm(bc_applied[,targets] ~ dsRNA, data = bc_applied)
```

The following error is returned:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = bc_applied[, targets] ~ dsRNA,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'bc_applied[, targets]'
```

The desired output is given by

```
lm(cbind(target1, target2) ~ dsRNA, data = bc_applied)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?lm`

> If response is a matrix a linear model is fitted separately by least-squares to each column of the matrix.

With `cbind`, it is creating a `matrix`.  So, we need an option that takes a `matrix`.  After subsetting the dataset with the columns, convert it to a `matrix` with `as.matrix` and it should work

```
lm(as.matrix(bc_applied[,targets]) ~ dsRNA, data = bc_applied)
```

-output

```
#Call:
#lm(formula = as.matrix(bc_applied[, targets]) ~ dsRNA, data = bc_applied)

#Coefficients:
#             target1   target2 
#(Intercept)   0.45161   0.47457
#dsRNAgene2    0.36341   0.29226
#dsRNAgene3   -0.07115  -0.03003
```

---

Or another option is to create a formula with `paste`

```
lm(paste0('cbind(', toString(targets),') ~ dsRNA'), data = bc_applied)
```

-output

```
#Call:
#lm(formula = paste0("cbind(", toString(targets), ") ~ dsRNA"), 
#    data = bc_applied)

#Coefficients:
#             target1   target2 
#(Intercept)   0.45161   0.47457
#dsRNAgene2    0.36341   0.29226
#dsRNAgene3   -0.07115  -0.03003
```

or create the `formula` with `glue`

```
lm(glue::glue('cbind({toString(targets)}) ~ dsRNA'), bc_applied)
```

---

or another option is

```
lm(do.call(cbind, asplit(bc_applied[, targets], 2)) ~ dsRNA, bc_applied)
```

---

Crosschecking with  `cbind`

```
lm(cbind(target1, target2)~ dsRNA, data = bc_applied)
```

-output

```
#Call:
#lm(formula = cbind(target1, target2) ~ dsRNA, data = bc_applied)

#Coefficients:
#             target1   target2 
#(Intercept)   0.45161   0.47457
#dsRNAgene2    0.36341   0.29226
#dsRNAgene3   -0.07115  -0.03003
```